# How to reduce javascript object to only contain properties from interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

When using typescript a declared interface could look like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  test: string;
}
```

And an implementation with extra property could be like this:

```
class MyTest implements MyInterface {
  test: string;
  newTest: string;
}
```

**Example** (here the variable 'reduced' still contain the property 'newTest'):

```
var test: MyTest = {test: "hello", newTest: "world"}

var reduced: MyInterface = test; // something clever is needed
```

**Question**

In a general way, how can you make the 'reduced' variable to only contain the properties declared in the 'MyInterface' interface.

**Why**

The problem occur when trying to use the 'reduced' variable with angular.toJson before sending it to a rest service - the toJson method transforms the newTest variable, even if it's not accessible on the instance during compile, and this makes the rest service not accept the json since it has properties that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. The reason being `interface` is a Typescript construct and the [transpiled JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChllIBnMALmUqlAHMBuIgXyKKA) is empty

```
//this code transpiles to empty!
interface MyInterface {
  test: string;
}
```

Thus at runtime there is nothing to 'work with' - no properties exist to interrogate.

The answer by @jamesmoey explains a workaround to achieve the desired outcome. 
A similar solution I use is simply to define the 'interface' as a class -

```
class MyInterface {
  test: string = undefined;
}
```

Then you can use `lodash` to pick the properties from the 'interface' to inject into you object:

```
import _ from 'lodash';  //npm i lodash

const before = { test: "hello", newTest: "world"};
let reduced = new MyInterface();
_.assign(reduced , _.pick(before, _.keys(reduced)));
console.log('reduced', reduced)//contains only 'test' property
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vooose/b8chfzyo/8/)

This is a pragmatic solution that has served me well without getting bogged down on semantics about whether it actually is an interface and/or naming conventions (e.g. `IMyInterface`  or `MyInterface`) and allows you to mock and unit test

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I updated the test variable so it's not the same name as the test property, to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 7):

TS 2.1 has Object Spread and Rest, so it is possible now:

```
var my: MyTest = {test: "hello", newTest: "world"}

var { test, ...reduced } = my;
```

After that reduced will contain all properties except of "test".

Comment: Could you please explain, what you mean by Object Spread and Rest? You mean the triple dots `...` right?

Comment: Yes. Object spread allows you to explode properties, Rest to cut properties away.

Comment: This works but it requires you to know exactly which properties will be "excess". What if you don't know that?

Comment: @medley56 I don't see how that's the case. It just requires you to know which properties you want to keep. You assign those by name, and discard the rest without exploding and assigning them.

Comment: @dwllama You have it backwards I think. The named properties are the discarded ones. `...reduced` is the part you want to keep (though you don't know what's in it except that it doesn't contain `test`).

Comment: @medley56 Actually, in the given example, neither is discarded. try throwing it in a plnkr real quick. `var my = {test: "hello", newTest: "world"}

var { test, ...reduced } = my;

console.log(test)

console.log(reduced)`
produces: `[Log] hello (script.js, line 7)
[Log] {newTest: "world"} (script.js, line 9)`

Answer (score 6):

Another possible approach:

As other answers have mentioned, you can't avoid doing something at runtime; TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, mostly by simply removing interface/type definitions, annotations, and assertions.  The type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types), and your `MyInterface` is nowhere to be found in the runtime code that needs it.

So, you will need something like an array of keys you want to keep in your reduced object:

```
const myTestKeys = ["test"] as const;
```

By itself this is fragile, since if `MyInterface` is modified, your code might not notice.  One possible way to make your code notice is to set up some type alias definitions that will cause a compiler error if `myTestKeys` doesn't match up with `keyof MyInterface`:

```
// the following line will error if myTestKeys has entries not in keyof MyInterface:
type ExtraTestKeysWarning<T extends never =
  Exclude<typeof myTestKeys[number], keyof MyInterface>> = void;
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'UNION_OF_EXTRA_KEY_NAMES_HERE' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'

// the following line will error if myTestKeys is missing entries from keyof MyInterface:
type MissingTestKeysWarning<T extends never =
  Exclude<keyof MyInterface, typeof myTestKeys[number]>> = void;
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'UNION_OF_MISSING_KEY_NAMES_HERE' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'
```

That's not very pretty, but if you change `MyInterface`, one or both of the above lines will give an error that hopefully is expressive enough that the developer can modify `myTestKeys`.

There are ways to make this more general, or possibly less intrusive, but almost no matter what you do, the best you can reasonably expect from TypeScript is that your code will give compiler warnings in the face of unexpected changes to an interface; not that your code will actually do different things at runtime.

---

Once you have the keys you care about you can write a `pick()` function that pulls just those properties out of an object:

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = obj[k], o), {} as Pick<T, K>);
}
```

And them we can use it on your `test` object to get `reduced`:

```
var test: MyTest = { test: "hello", newTest: "world" }

const reduced: MyInterface = pick(test, ...myTestKeys);

console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced)); // {"test": "hello"}
```

That works!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZSAZzAC5lqpQBzAblIF9SuTRJZEUGACoRqyCAA9IIACaU0WHP3zEyFUbXphGIVqXIgIAdxHU6DZmxKcS3APQPHTh9wQB7EGIC26U2ADSEOjyALzIANoARFRgkQC6yHDy7p5gVqQOFAAWKDBuADb5bkbMyPmgKCWF4lBQblDIwDDIPn6BwchZSeLgjKLIIG5gjSDIANZBbs0Y2Hx4EDSkYOgADigAolJQcG1BlADqcFAgzAA8QuJSELLyhgBu0Mgh+sibCPkArjIQp8trUy1fBp2pRwiAPl4AEbQOIAGnGk2mijmAgAfKinsg7m5gDIrA4AH5E4kk0lk8kUykUjJ2ZBCVYoADkAFUAHKYADyrIA+hyAGLc9YADSEACUAILc-zrACa3NZ4tQ6wAytyABLrUXrRnIGRufqDYaUOBgYCUGDobIoFIMOC8ZCM+7QRn2WlgHLIPKFYqlcqGZBVfI1OoNJqA3YdM0tM2UUrXbTAfowOpeBHoAEzJTzRYkP6CGPMCMHI4nXTnS7SOQDCAPBrPNRvT7fU4TdNI2a4ATwvMA1rAvZgiHQqBxdGY7G4-F2Kkz2dz8k0ukMh1szk8-nc1CYZXKzCsgDiUtl8sVKvVmu1uv1tyG9BNZotVuQNu0dvADqdUBdthIMA+IAQU0PGQFZgAQMZznhfwK2uKtWwBIRUQACjcSEACs6CEeEADpcNbSg6H8cI4gASjoAAFMCIKw5B-AxVRyCgCAwA+Y400obCmJkD4kCQlD4TGEingxFDwjGBIwlQtCxLhZA3BI+ECHYRJ5Eo8DINo1ESKsGwaWcJxuDuI51DMBQ-ExAgTM0SIcm9SJ4UMEwNDoSIjHqfIZEiZBdJIF9kC4niIBkOhMxRfAwlA8CkJiHDcL7agQW01wPEoAoIGwoomCQgApZUuWwixdCadAkICpAZBI7TkEyAhog0SIXNsopInYIA)

Comment: What is `myTestKeys` in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to only set/assign properties listed on the interface only? Functionality like that is not available in TypeScript but it is very simple to write a function to perform the behaviour you looking for.

```js
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {
 name: string = '';
}
class Staff implements IPerson {
 name: string = '';
    position: string = '';
}

var jimStaff: Staff = {
    name: 'Jim',
    position: 'Programmer'
};

var jim: Person = new Person();
limitedAssign(jimStaff, jim);
console.log(jim);

function limitedAssign<T,S>(source: T, destination: S): void {
    for (var prop in destination) {
        if (source[prop] && destination.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            destination[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something like what I'm after. I can't get it to work though. I believe it's because the properties on 'jim' are not initialized and it does not find any properties to loop through. Also - if it were some way to skip having a class 'Person' and just loop through the properties directly from IPerson - that would be perfect.

Comment: @TomasF I had the same issue and figured it out. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6515 as the underlying JS has no set default properties thus the `for` loop has no properties to iterate over. The solution is to add default values to every property like `name: string = '';`

Answer (score 1):

In your example **newTest** property won't be accessible thru the **reduced** variable, so that's the goal of using types. The typescript brings type checking, but it doesn't manipulates the object properties.

Comment: Our problem is that we try to use the 'reduced' variable with angular.toJson before sending it to a rest service - and the toJson transforms even the newTest variable even if it's not accessible from the instance.

Answer (score 1):

For me accepted answer provided by @wal  did not work since it only considers flat object use case. For nested fields it may get a bit more complicated. I ended up using neat package called Joi (https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi). Besides possibility to strip all unexpected fields tool provides validation capabilities, so not only you get sanitised data, but also can ensure that it contains what is expected and throws error if required field is missing or is of an invalid type etc. And you can define as complex schema as you wish

Small example:

```
import Joi from 'joi';
const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    items: Joi.array()
      .items(Joi.object({ id: Joi.string().required() }))
      .required(),
  });

  const result = Joi.attempt(
    {
      name: 'test',
      weirdField: 'bla bla bla',
      items: [{ id: '1', weirdField: 234 }],
    },
    schema,
    { stripUnknown: true },
  );

  console.log(result);
```

> { name: 'test', items: [ { id: '1' } ] }

Answer (score 0):

> In a general way, how can you make the 'reduced' variable to only contain the properties declared in the 'MyInterface' interface.

Since TypeScript is *structural* this means that anything that contains the relevant information is Type Compatible and therefore assignable.

That said, TypeScript 1.6 will get a concept called [`freshness`](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html). This will make it easier to catch clear *typos* (note freshness only applies to object literals):

```
// ERROR : `newText` does not exist on `MyInterface`
var reduced: MyInterface = {test: "hello", newTest: "world"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy example:

```
let all_animals = { cat: 'bob', dog: 'puka', fish: 'blup' };
const { cat, ...another_animals } = all_animals;
console.log(cat); // bob
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use a `class` instead of an `interface` and use a `factory method` (a public static member function that returns a new object of it's type). The model is the only place where you know the allowed properties and it's the place where you don't forget to update them accidentaly on model changes.

```
class MyClass {
  test: string;

  public static from(myClass: MyClass): MyClass {
    return {test: myClass.test};
  }
}
```

Example:

```
class MyTest extends MyClass {
  test: string;
  newTest: string;
}

const myTest: MyTest = {test: 'foo', newTest: 'bar'};
const myClass: MyClass = MyClass.from(myTest);
```