# Properties selection for spread operator in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am probably missing some advanced feature of typescript to solve the following problem. Having a complex intersection type, I would like to spread its properties limited to one of its base types.

```js
//In this simple example T1 and T2 have just a a few properties each.
//In my real app there are more types with dozens of properties.
//They come from external libraries, I can't assume anything.

interface T1 { a: number, b:number }
interface T2 { c: string }

type T = T1 & T2;

const o: T = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 'abc' };

console.log({...o}) //{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 'abc' } as expected
//How to get only properties of T1? That is {a: 1, b: 2}?
```

How to spread only properties of `T1` from `o` into the new object? Is there an elegant simple way in typescript? The desired output for this example would be `{ a: 1, b: 2}`.

Here are my failed attempts:

```
//just typechecking, still returns { a: 1, b: 2, c: 'abc' }
console.log({...(o as T1)})

//destructing works only for single properties, not for whole types 
const { ??, ...rest } = z;
```

Comment: Since javascript has no shorthand for doing this, neither does typescript.

Comment: Note: `T1 & T2` is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you, fixed that!

Comment: Short answer: you need to have a list of the properties you want to keep or exclude at runtime; `interface` definitions are completely erased by the compiler so you can't access `T1` or its keys in your property-spreading code.

Comment: That is bad news. The type I want to extract is declared in a 3rd-party library. Hard-coding its properties for the extraction is definitely bad practice, since changing the declaration there would immediately break my code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The question you both referenced asks almost the same and yes, it answers my question unfortunately stating that there is no solution.

Comment: There *is* a solution but it might not be as simple as you want.  See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-vpv8m), for example. Watch what happens if you change the keys of `T1` (either add more or remove one); your code will then get compiler errors so you will know to change it.  This isn't as good as doing it "automatically", but it's much better than nothing.  From a JS point of view, if the third-party changes the keys of an interface, then code relying on the old definitions is definitely going to break, right? Is there a way around that? All we can do is notice.

Comment: You should also be sure that you really *need* to remove those extra properties.  What does it break to leave them in?  Object interfaces in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  You know your use case best, though.  If you are interested in the above suggestion in the sandbox I can write it up (or possibly find another answer that uses something like this)

Comment: @jcalz My use-case is that I am writing a higher-order component in React. As I like things clean, I didn't want to flood a child component (the original that gets wrapped) with props it doesn't need. Fortunately, I can control the intersection type. Now designed it in a different way `interface T = {t1: T1, t2: T2}` so I can select each of them by spread. On the other hand I also highly appreaciate your example checking the symmetric difference as it comes reasonably close to a general solution. Would you like to write it down as an answer? I would reopen the Q for that.

Comment: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61684563/2887218) in the question this duplicates, for what it's worth.