# Common properties from two interfaces using generic

Tags: typescript

```
interface userDetails{
      name:string;
      age:number;
    }
    interface json{
        name:string;
        age:number;
        address:string
    }
export function createListItems<K,l>(jsonData:K[]): l[]{
    let items: l[] = [];
    type P=keyof l;
    for(let i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
        let obj:Partial<Record<P,l[P]>>={};
           ...I want to fetch only l properties(name,age) from k(name,age,addrees) and store it in obj. how can I do that.
    }
    .
    items.push(obj as l);
    return items;
}
createListItems<json,userDetails>({[name:"sunny",age:20,address:"pune"],[name:"minnu",age:20,address:"pune"]});
```

I want to fetch `useDetails` interface properties from json interface and push it to array. How to do that with generic approach. Something like
`let obj:Partial<Record<keyof l,string|boolean>={}`
At the end obj need to have name and age properties fetched from json interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash pick method here.
The _.pick() method is used to return a copy of the object that is composed of the picked object properties.

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

const keysOfL = keys<l>();

console.log(_.pick(obj, keysOfL));
```

Once you have the keys you care about you can write a pick() function that pulls just those properties out of an object:

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return keys.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = obj[k], o), {} as Pick<T, K>);
}
```

And them we can use it on your test object to get reduced:

```
interface MyInterface {
  test: string;
}
interface MyTest {
  test: string;
  newTest: string;
}    
var test: MyTest = { test: "hello", newTest: "world" }
    
    const reduced: MyInterface = pick(test, ...myTestKeys);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced)); // {"test": "hello"}
```

That works!

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829951/how-to-reduce-javascript-object-to-only-contain-properties-from-interface).

Comment: for myTestKeys i need keys[] right. But in my code how can i get keys array from interface l If implement pick function.

Comment: keyof is a keyword in TypeScript which is used to extract the key type from an object type.

Comment: to lodash we cannot give keyof l because it is type right.

Comment: export function createListItems<k,l>(jsonData:j[]): l[]{
    let items: l[] = [];
    for(let i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++){
      let obj=_.pick(jsonData[i],keyof l); // not taking keyof l in lodash 
    }
    
    return items;
}                                                                                                                                     
let z=[{name:"bhanu",age:20,address:"address"},{name:"kailash",age:20, address:" "}];
let x:userDetails[]=createListItems<json, userDetails>(z);
console.log(x);  //l is json interface and k json interface

Comment: keyof l returns type right something like "name"|"age" but not as value. From l interface how can i get keys as array like ["name","age"]; So that I can we can reduce on that.

Comment: updated the answer for the query,