# How to copy only fields from a generic type alias in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

For the following type alias:

```js
export type Editable<Data extends object> = {
    _backup: Data
    canRefresh: boolean
    canEdit: boolean
    canSave: boolean
    canCancel: boolean
    canDelete: boolean
    canUndelete: boolean

    /* More stuff deleted for brevity */
} & Data
```

I want to write a function that will copy the fields of `Data` to and from the `_backup` so that I can save and restore the state of the `Data`, but not backup/restore the additional fields that are introduced by `Editable<Data>`.

I tried writing them like this, but I get compiler errors and can't figure out how to make this work. Note that I specifically do not want to backup and restore the additional fields that are introduced by `Editable`.

```js
function backup<Data extends object>(editable: Editable<Data>): void {
    if (!editable._backup) editable._backup = {} as Data
    let key: keyof Data
    for (key in editable) editable._backup[key] = editable[key]
}

function restore<Data extends object>(editable: Editable<Data>): void {
   if (editable._backup) {
       let key: keyof Data
       for (key in editable) editable[key] = editable._backup[key]
   }
}
```

I read several other Q&A on SO (including [How to reduce javascript object to only contain properties from interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829951/how-to-reduce-javascript-object-to-only-contain-properties-from-interface)), but they all rely on `Object.keys(editable)` which will copy all of the fields of the object, not just the ones defined by `Data`. The solutions presented in other questions also relate to situations in which both types are known. My situation is different because I am writing a generic type, and the actual type of the data is unknown.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: TS type info is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from emitted JS so you can't consult those keys. You'll essentially need an array of keys at runtime, or some other approach. See the linked question and its answers for more information.